# polars groupby and pivot converting code from pyspark

Tags: pyspark, python-polars

Currently converting some code from pyspark to polars which i need some help with

In pyspark i am grouping by col1 and col2 then pivoting on column called VariableName using
the Value column.how would I do this in polars?

```
pivotDF = df.groupBy("col1","col2").pivot("VariableName").max("Value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this data:

```py
import polars as pl
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["A", "B"] * 12,
        "col2": ["x", "y", "z"] * 8,
        "VariableName": ["one", "two", "three", "four"] * 6,
        "Value": pl.arange(0, 24, eager=True),
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (24, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────────┬───────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ VariableName ┆ Value │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---          ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str          ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════════╪═══════╡
│ A    ┆ x    ┆ one          ┆ 0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ y    ┆ two          ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ z    ┆ three        ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ x    ┆ four         ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...          ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ z    ┆ one          ┆ 20    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ x    ┆ two          ┆ 21    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ y    ┆ three        ┆ 22    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ z    ┆ four         ┆ 23    │
└──────┴──────┴──────────────┴───────┘
```

Running your query on pyspark yields:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
(
    spark
    .createDataFrame(df.to_pandas())
    .groupBy("col1", "col2")
    .pivot("VariableName")
    .max("Value")
    .sort(["col1", "col2"])
    .show()
)
```

```
+----+----+----+----+-----+----+                                                
|col1|col2|four| one|three| two|
+----+----+----+----+-----+----+
|   A|   x|null|  12|   18|null|
|   A|   y|null|  16|   22|null|
|   A|   z|null|  20|   14|null|
|   B|   x|  15|null| null|  21|
|   B|   y|  19|null| null|  13|
|   B|   z|  23|null| null|  17|
+----+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

In Polars, we would code this using [`pivot`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html).

```py
(
    df
    .pivot(
        index=["col1", "col2"],
        values="Value",
        columns="VariableName",
        aggregate_fn="max",
    )
    .sort(["col1", "col2"])
)
```

```
shape: (6, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ one  ┆ two  ┆ three ┆ four │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ A    ┆ x    ┆ 12   ┆ null ┆ 18    ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ y    ┆ 16   ┆ null ┆ 22    ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ z    ┆ 20   ┆ null ┆ 14    ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ x    ┆ null ┆ 21   ┆ null  ┆ 15   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ y    ┆ null ┆ 13   ┆ null  ┆ 19   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ z    ┆ null ┆ 17   ┆ null  ┆ 23   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┘
```